# jQuery change background

Tags: jquery, background

```
 $(function() {

   //Indicate here the version of your forum.
   var version = "phpbb2";

   if(version.toLowerCase() == "phpbb2"){   
      $(".postdetails img[title='Premium']").closest('.postdetails').parent('td').next('td').addClass("fa_postbody_xy");
      $(".postdetails img[title='Junior']").closest('.postdetails').parent('td').next('td').addClass("fa_postbody_xx");
   }else if(version.toLowerCase() == "phpbb3"){   
      $(".postprofile img[title='Male']").closest('.postprofile').prev('.postbody').addClass("fa_postbody_xy");
      $(".postprofile img[title='Female']").closest('.postprofile').prev('.postbody').addClass("fa_postbody_xx");   
   }else if(version.toLowerCase() == "punbb"){   
      $(".user-info img[title='Male']").closest('.postmain').addClass("fa_postbody_xy");
      $(".user-info img[title='Female']").closest('.postmain').addClass("fa_postbody_xx");   
   }else if(version.toLowerCase() == "invision"){         
      $(".postprofile img[title='Male']").closest('.post-container').addClass("fa_postbody_xy");
      $(".postprofile img[title='Female']").closest('.post-container').addClass("fa_postbody_xx");
   }
});
```

that is the code i am working with. now what I want to do to this is make it so instead of .postdetails img[ id like to go to this ul class .profile_field_list li[text="premium"]

is this possible?

```
<ul class="profile_field_list">
<li>Premium Member</li>
</ul>
```

and thats the html that i would like to find and then do what it says in the code...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var title = $("ul#profile_field_list li:first").attr("id");
```

Modify your markup as

```
<ul class="profile_field_list">
<li id="Premium Member">Premium Member</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: problem with modifing markup is that this is an auto generated markup through php files. everyone on the forum has different labels,Premium,junior,elite,first class, and so forth. Their groups change after doing certain things. So i would need to find the text string in the li. This would work most likely 100% if i could do what you asked. Thank you though.